# $f$ is continuous if and only if $\text{osc}(f,x) = 0$ in a generic Hausdorff space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a  Hausdorff topological space and $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function.  Let $x\in X$ and  $U(x)$ being the of neighbourhood sets of $x$. Define the oscillation of $f$ at $x$ by $$\text{osc}(f,x) = \inf_{V \in U(x)}\bigg\{\sup \big\{|f(z) - f(y)| : z, y \in V\big\}\bigg\}.$$

Prove that $f$ is continuous if and only if $\text{osc}(f,x) = 0$,
the set $\{x \in X : \text{osc}(f) \geq \varepsilon\}$, where $\varepsilon \geq 0$, is closed and that the sets:
$$\{x \in X : f \text{ continuous at } \ x\} \quad \{x \in X : f \text{ not continuous at } \ x\}$$
are a $G_\delta$ and a $F_\sigma$ set respectively.
I've seen many solutions to this problem, but they all have in common that $X$ is a metric space, but I have no metric to work with, so I don't even know how to handle this problem.

Comment: The first thing I'd try do is look at the metric space proof, and whenever they talk about separating two points by open balls of some radius, instead use the Hausdorff property to separate the points with disjoint neighbourhoods. Also replace open balls by open neighbourhoods in general. 

Then check your `new' proof, and see if works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $f$ is continous at $x$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\operatorname{osc}(f,x) = 0$:

$\Rightarrow$: Let $\epsilon > 0$. There exists $V \in U(x)$ such that $\lvert f(y) - f(x) \rvert < \epsilon/2$ for all $y \in V$ . Then for all $y,z \in V$ we have $\lvert f(y) - f(z) \rvert < \epsilon$, thus $\sup \big\{|f(z) - f(y)| : z, y \in V\big\} \le \epsilon$. Hence  $\operatorname{osc}(f,x) \le \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. We conclude  $\operatorname{osc}(f,x) = 0$.

$\Leftarrow$: Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $\operatorname{osc}(f,x) = 0$, there exists $V \in U(x)$ such that $\sup \big\{|f(z) - f(y)| : z, y \in V\big\} <\epsilon$. Therefore $\lvert f(y) - f(x) \rvert < \epsilon$ for all $y \in V$.

2. $\{x \in X :\operatorname{osc}(f,x) \geq \varepsilon\}$ is closed:

This is same as $X_\epsilon = \{x \in X :\operatorname{osc}(f,x) < \varepsilon\}$ being open. So let $x \in X_\epsilon$. There exists $V \in U(x)$ such that $\sup \big\{|f(z) - f(y)| : z, y \in V\big\} < \epsilon$. We claim that $V \subset X_\epsilon$. If $x' \in V$, then clearly $V \in U(x')$. Since $\sup \big\{|f(z) - f(y)| : z, y \in V\big\} < \epsilon$, we see that $\operatorname{osc}(f,x') < \varepsilon$, i.e. $x' \in X_\epsilon$.

3. $\{x \in X : f \text{ continuous at } \ x\}$ is a $G_\delta$ set:

We have $\operatorname{osc}(f,x) = 0$ iff $\operatorname{osc}(f,x) < 1/n$ for all $n$, i.e. $x \in  X_{1/n}$ for all $n$. Hence
$$\{x \in X : f \text{ continuous at } \ x\} =\{x \in X : \operatorname{osc}(f,x) = 0 \} = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty X_{1/n}$$

4. $\{x \in X : f \text{ not continuous at } \ x\}$ is an $F_\sigma$ set:

This set is the complement of the $G_\delta$ set $\{x \in X : f \text{ continuous at } \ x\}$, thus it is an $F_\sigma$ set.

*Remark:*

We did not use that $X$ is Hausdorff.